# What are the health implications of using ethylene glycol to treat athletes foot (tinea pedis)

Tags: athletes-foot

I found this article about [the treatment of rot in wooden boats](http://www.simplicityboats.com/chemorot.html), which in the 11th paragraph from the top mentions the use of common [ethylene glycol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene_glycol) based antifreeze for the treatment of [athletes foot (tinea pedis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlete's_foot).

Does anyone know about any medical research done on this topic, or failing that, the health impact on externally applied ethylene glycol? To narrow down the expected quantity of exposure I would propose an initial treatment of maybe twice a day for a week going down to maybe once a week to prevent any new outbreaks. Areas to be treated are the soles of both feet, the toes with the area between them, under the toe nails and the area on top of the toes. Basically the same area as recommended for commercially available treatments for athlete foot like clotrimazole

I would guess this is still below the actual exposure that any car mechanic would get on a daily base during his/her work.

Information that includes any impact of common (anti corrosion) additives found in commercially available antifreeze fluid are welcome if kept separate from those of ethylene glycol specifically.